# Немного едет верстка на телефонах

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Кто знает, почему на одних телефонах едет верстка, а на других нет? Причем в инспекторе 320-1920 все нормально выглядит. Напишу [ссылку](http://test.aleksandernitchenko.ru/) на всякий случай. Также 2 изображения как в инспекторе показывает на 6 айфоне и как на самом 6 айфоне
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что разные браузеры по-разному поддерживают разные возможности. Хром показывает так, как умеет он, а многие мобильные браузеры поддерживают меншье возможностей чем хром. Особенно айфон

Comment: а как демонстрировать сайт с одинаковым отображением для всех устройств

Comment: Никак. Пишите код аккуратно, используйте только поддерживаемые браузерами возможности и проверяйте всё на всех устройствах прямо во время разработки, а не когда всё уже закончили

Answer (score 2):

Потому что на одних и на других телефонах стоят разные версии браузеров, которые по-разному могут обрабатывать все что угодно. Найдите в сети любой сайт, который покажет вам `user-agent` вашего браузера и убедитесь сами.

П.С. А инспектор на вашем компьютере - это вообще часть другого браузера. При отладке по USB браузер телефона выдает в компьютер свои данные, но рендерится-то содержимое браузером компьютера, а не телефона. Всякие там режимы совместимости - меньше чем полумеры.

Comment: на blackberкy 2013 года отображает нормально, а на 6 iphone и meizu новом чуток едет - вот что удивляет. и на последних наблюдается во всех браузерах. Это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: Я бы посмотрел, если бы по вашей ссылке выдавало требуемую страницу, а не затычку "You have successfully installed MODX"...

Comment: прошу прощения, поправил ссылку, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну... могу только присоединиться к комментариям к вашему вопросу. Нужно заранее проверять что поддерживают разные браузеры,а что нет. У меня не айфон, поэтому ваш сайт расползся немного по-другому - как минимум потому ,что браузер не поддерживает css expressions и, как следствие, функцию calc().

Comment: Добавлю только, что инспектор покажет вам только разрешение, пропорции тех телефонов, что там есть в списке. То как сработает конкретный браузер, на конкретном устройстве вы можете проверить либо непосредственно на устройстве либо с помощью виртуальной машины на вашем пк, либо при помощи сервисов, которые запускают на своей стороне виртуальные машины.

Comment: calc используется в smart-grid, так я им особо не пользуюсь

Comment: я calc() как пример привел. воспользуйтесь сайтом https://www.caniuse.com для проверки что из  использованного вами где поддерживается.